# Windows Server 2019 NPS PEAP not working with Internal CA, But works with self signed

Tags: nps

i've got trouble with NPS on 1 of my customers sites which wont authenticate with EAP when using the internal CA certificates. I've tried 4-6 variation of the internal certificate to no avail..

NPS log shows nothing. Account log shows this:

> <EventTimestamp data_type="4">04/02/2021 13:17:53.720/Timestamp><Computer-Name data_type="1"SERVICES</Computer-NameIAS272311 1 10.1.20.20 04/02/2021 10:57:31 50</ClassSession-Timeout data_type="0">30/Session-Timeout>10.1.21.11<Client-Vendor data_type="0"0/Client-Vendor><Client-Friendly-Name data_type="1"NETWORK/Client-Friendly-Name><NP-Policy-Name data_type="1"Connections to Microsoft Routing and Remote Access server5Use Windows authentication for all users1/Provider-TypeSAM-Account-Name data_type="1">XXX\antpal/SAM-Account-Name>Fully-Qualifed-User-Name data_type="1"XXX\antpal /Fully-Qualifed-User-Name Packet-Type data_type="0"11/Packet-Type> Reason-Code data_type="0" 0 /Reason-Code /Event

On the client side it's stuck at verifying credentials.

Note that if i choose a self signed certificate this works just fine. I don't know which log to refer to next here.

Ideas?

Comment: Solved by enteringe Framed-mtu to 1100.